# Multiple Database on Codeigniter not working as expected on a custom library during get_instance

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

The ff is my database setup on my config file

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '#########';
$db['default']['database'] = 'fault_analytics';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
...

$db['SiteDB']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['SiteDB']['username'] = 'root';
$db['SiteDB']['password'] = '#########';
$db['SiteDB']['database'] = 'smartSiteDB';
$db['SiteDB']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
...
```

my custom jcm_acl.php construct method:

```
function __construct() {
    $this->ci =& get_instance();
    $this->ci->load->helper('url');
    $this->ci->load->library('session');
    $this->ci->load->helper('string');
    $this->ci->load->config('jcm_acl');
    $this->ci->load->model('jcm_acl_model', 'acl');

    $this->tables = $this->ci->config->item('tables');
    $this->default_error_page = $this->ci->config->item('default_error_page');
    $this->use_default_error_page = $this->ci->config->item('use_default_error_page');
 }
```

I ran some debug queries to check the database captured by my `get_instance()` on my custom library's `__construct()` method. The ff are my debug queries:

```
vdebug($this->jcm_acl->ci->db->database);
vdebug($this->jcm_acl->ci->db->list_tables());
vdebug($this->jcm_acl->ci->db->get('users'));
die();
```

Below are the results of the debug queries:
[image: vdebug($this->jcm_acl->ci->db->database);]

[image: vdebug($this->jcm_acl->ci->db->list_tables());]

[image: $this->jcm_acl->ci->db->get('users')]

Notice the database name being referred to by the `get()` method, its not the same with the database name as shown by the first debug query. How is this happening.

This only happens when I access the page where I also load the second database. On other pages where I do not load the second database, It works perfectly fine.

Comment: can u show me ur `__construct` method

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: found this note from codeigniter documentation "You don’t need to create separate database configurations if you only need to use a different database on the same connection. You can switch to a different database when you need to, like this:
$this->db->db_select($database2_name);" Could this be the reason? ref: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/connecting.html